# Rack::Test resulting in ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork

I have a problem when running all of my specs.

```
    ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Affiliate(#2154746360) expected, got Affiliate(#2199508660)
```

It would appear that my models are being loaded twice.

I have isolated the problem to be introduced with Rack::Test's requirement to define an "app" method.

```
require 'rack/test'
include Rack::Test::Methods

# app method is needed for rack-test
def app
  Rails.application
end
```

If I comment out `Rails.application` my rack specs do not work, but all of my other specs work fine.  The use of `Rails.application` in the "app" method introduces the error above.

If I run my specs individually, everything works.  I am preloading my environment with Spork and I think that the models are loaded first by Spork and then they are redefined when `Rails.application` is called in my "app" method.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this problem?  I am not sure if there is another way to set my Rails app in the "app" method.

Comment: We've been running into precisely the same issue, and have been quite unsuccessful in sussing it out. Have you had any luck?

Comment: Seems like there's some action on the factory_girl Google Group on this issue: http://groups.google.com/group/factory_girl/browse_thread/thread/daa24556d90c31fc

Comment: Michael, I have not had any luck with it so far. I have just avoided running the offending specs with the rest of my specs. It is a pain.

Comment: I did end up solving this, but I don't know exactly what change in my refactoring did the trick. I think it's possible the problem was that my Rspec config block was outsite of Spork's prefork, but that doesn't really sit right with me. If it's helpful, I can go through my changes and try to isolate what actually fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no longer having this problem anymore. I updated my gems.  Rails was updated from 3.0.5 to 3.0.7 and I would guess that may have been the gem update that fixed my problem. Either way with newer versions of gems, my problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From source code for `Rails.application`:

```
# File railties/lib/rails.rb, line 34
def application
  @@application ||= nil
end
```

This means that `Rails.application` returns the same object every time. Maybe this is the problem - running multiple tests on the same Rails app clashes with objects.

[Some tutorials](http://lds.li/post/671889754/rack-test-with-rails-3-rspec) set tests up like this:

```
def app
  Rails::Application
end
```

Whereas [others](http://jackhq.tumblr.com/post/1005556645/using-rack-test-for-rails-and-restful-apis) do it like this:

```
def app
  ActionController::Dispatcher.new
end
```

Both of which create new object for each call to `app`.

**EDIT:** Just noticed from logs that `ActionController::Dispatcher.new` is marked as deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, but after updating my gems things seem to have sorted their way out.